# Why do I get KeyEventArgs from XAML but RoutedEventArgs from C# when I refer to the exact same KeyDown event?

Tags: wpf, xaml, events

This must be something simple but I can't seem to google it easily.

e.g. `<TextBox Name="blah" KeyDown="TextboxKEYDOWN">`

And now C# can use an events function with KeyEventArgs available

but if I do in C# `blah.KeyDown += (s, r) => TextboxKEYDOWN(s, e);`

then TextboxKEYDOWN only gets RoutedEventArgs  and complains that it can't cast KeyEventArgs to it.

Why is that and can it be used as normal from C# only?

PS. I have a feeling this is something too simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because in

```
blah.KeyDown += (s, r) => TextboxKEYDOWN(s, e);
```

`r` is apparently not identical to `e` (no idea though what `e` is in your code sample).

You should however be able to write it as

```
blah.KeyDown += TextboxKEYDOWN;
```

where the handler method should look like this

```
private void TextboxKEYDOWN(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I haven't tested it yet to confirm it's related because I found it a better solution to do it in styles for all elements related. The 'e' was there because 'r' was used for a for loop :P I know, silly reason. I like the plain assignment.

Comment: OK, apparently, if I use a single and unused variable name for eventargs, it still gives a code-behind warning/error that it can not convert from routedeventargs to keyeventargs. Your method though with the plain assignment works perfectly! So I'll just accept the answer. If anyone has a bonus of guessing why the code doesn't like it explictly, that'd be fine.

Comment: And now it just worked. I'll just file it under "some typo messed it up for a while". :D Nothing to see here move along.